# How to define mapping for all future field in elastic search

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping

I am using template on elasticsearch 1.1.1 which is creating special mapping at index creation. 
My template is as following :

```
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "foo": {
      "properties": {
        "where": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "*": {
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "geo_point": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There will be future fields in the nested object "where". I would like them to not be analyzed to avoid tokenization during a terms Faceting. Unfortunately I do not know the name of this future fields when my index is created.

Do you know any way of defining a mapping for any future field in a nested or inner object ?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic templates for this, along with the index template that you already posted. Have a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates).

You can specify patterns that match your fields and have mappings apply to them instead of the usual defaults.